# About the maximal condition on subgroups and normality

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group which satisfies the maximal condition on subgroups. Now, let $H$ be a subgroup containing a non trivial conjugate (i.e. there exists an element $x\in G,\,\notin H $ such that $H^x\leq H$). Is it true that, in this case, $H$ is normal in $G$? How can we prove that? Is solvability of any help?

**Note**

A group $G$ is said to satisfy the maximal condition on subgroups iff it is impossibile to find an infinite strictly ascendant chain of subgroups.

Comment: What is "the maximal condition on subgroups"?

Comment: A group $G$ is said to satisfy the maximal condition on subgroups iff it is impossibile to find an infinite strictly ascendant chain of subgroups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that any **finite** nilpotent group $\;G\;$ both fulfills the maximal condition for subgroups and also for *any* proper subgroup $\;H\;$ we have that $\;H\lneqq N_G(H)\;$ which means there exists $\;x\in G\setminus H\;\;s.t.\;\;H^x\le H\;$ ...and this doesn't make the subgroup $\;H\;$ normal.

Comment: Which, of course, was basically my answer. Congrats!

Comment: True. As I said, congrats!

Answer (score -2):

I may be missing something, but the maximal condition simply tells you that if $H^x \leq H$ then $H^x = H.$ In other words, $H$ has normalizer strictly containing $H.$ It does not seem to imply that $H$ is normal.

Comment: I think that I'm allowed to consider the solvable case. Is it possibile to say more in this case?

Comment: Anyway how do you say that the maximal condition implies that $H^x\leq H\implies H^x=H$. I think that the minimal one can imply that, don't you agree?

Comment: @W4cco Take $K=H^x.$ Then $K^{x^{-1}}$ strictly contains $K.$

Comment: I do not understand. I think you're maybe assuming that $H^x$ is maximal in $G$? I was considering the impossibility to find an ascendant chain of subgroups of $G$ (which equivalently means that every subgroup is finitely generated).

Comment: Nope, I am assuming no such thing.

Comment: Can you provide me more details please?

Comment: @rschwieb I think, in your counterexample, must be $H=\langle x\rangle$ and $y^{-1}Hy$ strictly contained in $H$.

Comment: $H^x < H$ implies $H < H^y$ with $y=x^{-1}$. Then $H<H^y<H^{y^2} < ...$, contradicting the maximal condition on subgroups. The minimal condition on subgroups would similarly imply $H^x=H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I believe that's what I said :(

Comment: @Igor: It was, but not everybody seemed to believe it, so I thought I would offer you my support! I have no idea why you are getting negative votes. I'll give you a positive one.

Comment: @rschwieb: nobody claimed that $H^x \subseteq H$ implies $H^x=H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks, I figured that. My comment was actually along the lines of "they don't listen, do they..." Oh well.

Comment: Dear @DerekHolt : OK, thanks for translating. I mistook the response to the OP's first comment question for the fake-proof that this is so.

Comment: Dear: @IgorRivin : Sorry about misreading that, but the explanation in this solution is very thin, and easy to mistake the intent. Perhaps you could add Derek's explanation (or any sort of hint about the ascending chain)? I would very much like to see the improvement. Also if I make another mistake, feel free to say "no I mean (this)" rather than making no effort to communicate and then making sour comments about it. I don't mind getting corrected! Thank you.

Comment: @rschwieb thanks for the explanation, and I certainly wasn't blaming you. As for adding more, I am not sure where you are, but where I am it is the middle of the day, and there are other things going on. Also, I am sure all of us are trying to reverse engineer what the question actually was supposed to be...